# Speeding up operations on large arrays & datasets (Pandas slow, Numpy better, further improvements?)

Tags: python, pandas, performance, numpy, optimization

I have a large dataset comprising millions of rows and around 6 columns. The data is currently in a Pandas dataframe and I'm looking for the fastest way to operate on it. For example, let's say I want to drop all the rows where the value in one column is "1".

Here's my minimal working example:

```
# Create dummy data arrays and pandas dataframe
array_size = int(5e6)
array1 = np.random.rand(array_size)
array2 = np.random.rand(array_size)
array3 = np.random.rand(array_size)
array_condition = np.random.randint(0, 3, size=array_size)

df = pd.DataFrame({'array_condition': array_condition, 'array1': array1, 'array2': array2, 'array3': array3})

def method1():
    df_new = df.drop(df[df.array_condition == 1].index)
```

EDIT: As Henry Yik pointed out in the comments, a faster Pandas approach is this:

```
def method1b():
    df_new = df[df.array_condition != 1]
```

I believe that Pandas can be quite slow at this sort of thing, so I also implemented a method using numpy, processing each column as a separate array:

```
def method2():
    masking = array_condition != 1
    array1_new = array1[masking]
    array2_new = array2[masking]
    array3_new = array3[masking]
    array_condition_new = array_condition[masking]
```

And the results:

```
%timeit method1()
625 ms ± 7.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit methodb()
158 ms ± 7.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit method2()
138 ms ± 3.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

So we do see a slight significant performance boost using numpy. However, this is at the cost of much less readable code (i.e. having to create a mask and apply it to each array). This method doesn't seem as scalable either as if I have, say, 30 columns of data, I'll need a lot of lines of code that apply the mask to every array! Additionally, it would be useful to allow optional columns, so this method may fail trying to operate on arrays which are empty.

Therefore, I have 2 questions:

1) Is there a cleaner / more flexible way to implement this in numpy?

2) Or better, is there any higher performance method I could use here? e.g. JIT (numba?), Cython or something else?

PS, in practice, in-place operations can be used, replacing the old array with the new one once data is dropped

Comment: Why do you need to drop the rows instead of just using `df_new = df[df.array_condition != 1]`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I agree this is much better. Have added this to the original post. This is still a bit slower than numpy though so I'm still interested in improvements. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Part 1: Pandas and (maybe) Numpy

Compare your *method1b* and *method2*:

- *method1b* generates a **DataFrame**, which is probably what you want,
- *method2* generates a **Numpy array**, so to get fully comparable result,
  you should subsequently generate a *DataFrame* from it.

So I changed your *method2* to:

```
def method2():
    masking = array_condition != 1
    array1_new = array1[masking]
    array2_new = array2[masking]
    array3_new = array3[masking]
    array_condition_new = array_condition[masking]
    df_new = pd.DataFrame({ 'array_condition': array_condition[masking],
        'array1': array1_new, 'array2': array2_new, 'array3': array3_new})
```

and then compared execution times (using *%timeit*).

The result was that my (expanded) version of *method2* executed about 5% **longer**
than *method1b* (check on your own).

So my opinion is that as long as a **single** operation is concerned,
it is probably better to stay with *Pandas*.

But if you want to perform on your source DataFrame **a couple of** operations
in sequence and / or you are satisfied with the result as a *Numpy* array,
it is worth to:

- Call `arr = df.values` to get the underlying *Numpy* array.
- Perform all required operations on it using *Numpy* methods.
- (Optionally) create a DataFrame from the final reslut.

I tried *Numpy* version of *method1b*:

```
def method3():
    a = df.values
    arr = a[a[:,0] != 1]
```

but the execution time was about **40 % longer**.

The reason is probably that *Numpy* array has all elements of the
same type, so *array_condition* column is coerced to *float* and then
the whole *Numpy* array is created, what takes some time.

## Part 2: Numpy and Numba

An alternative to consider is to use *Numba* package - a Just-In-Time
Python compiler.

I made such test:

Created a *Numpy* array (as a preliminary step):

```
a = df.values
```

The reason is that JIT compiled methods are able to use *Numpy* methods and types,
but **not** those of *Pandas*.

To perform the test, I used almost the same method as above,
but with *@njit* annotation (requires *from numba import njit*):

```
@njit
def method4():
    arr = a[a[:,0] != 1]
```

This time:

- The execution time was about 45 % of the time for *method1b*.
- But since `a = df.values` has been executed **before** the test loop,
  there are doubts whether this result is comparable with earlier tests.

Anyway, try *Numba* on your own, maybe it will be an interesting option for you.

Answer (score 0):

You may find using [numpy.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) useful here. It converts a Boolean mask to array indices, making life much cheaper. Combining this with numpy.vstack allows for some memory-cheap operations:

```
def method3():
    wh = np.where(array_condition == 1)
    return np.vstack(tuple(col[wh] for col in (array1, array2, array3)))
```

This gives the following timeits:

```
>>> %timeit method2()
180 ms ± 6.66 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
>>> %timeit method3()
96.9 ms ± 2.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Tuple unpacking allows the operation to be fairly light on memory, as when the object is vstack-ed back together, it is smaller. If you need to get your columns out of a DataFrame directly, the following code snippet may be useful:

```
def method3b():
    wh = np.where(array_condition == 1)
    col_names = ['array1','array2','array3']
    return np.vstack(tuple(col[wh] for col in tuple(df[col_name].to_numpy() 
        for col_name in col_names)))
```

This allows one to grab columns by name from the DataFrame, which are then tuple unpacked on the fly. The speed is about the same:

```
>>> %timeit method3b()
96.6 ms ± 3.09 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Enjoy!